# How to access unexported struct fields

Tags: go, struct, reflection, unsafe-pointers

Is there a way to use reflect to access unexported fields in Go 1.8?
This no longer seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17982725/555493

Note that `reflect.DeepEqual` works just fine (that is, it can access unexported fields) but I can't make heads or tails of that function. Here's a go playarea that shows it in action: https://play.golang.org/p/vyEvay6eVG. The src code is below

```
import (
"fmt"
"reflect"
)

type Foo struct {
  private string
}

func main() {
    x := Foo{"hello"}
    y := Foo{"goodbye"}
    z := Foo{"hello"}

    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x,y)) //false
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(x,z)) //true
}
```

Answer (score 58):

If the struct is addressable, you can use `unsafe.Pointer` to access the field (read *or write*) it, like this:

```
rs := reflect.ValueOf(&MyStruct).Elem()
rf := rs.Field(n)
// rf can't be read or set.
rf = reflect.NewAt(rf.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(rf.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
// Now rf can be read and set.
```

[See full example on the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/DXXHuIvRLI)

This use of `unsafe.Pointer` is valid according to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer) and running `go vet` returns no errors.

If the struct is not addressable this trick won't work, but you can create an addressable copy like this:

```
rs = reflect.ValueOf(MyStruct)
rs2 := reflect.New(rs.Type()).Elem()
rs2.Set(rs)
rf = rs2.Field(0)
rf = reflect.NewAt(rf.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(rf.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
// Now rf can be read.  Setting will succeed but only affects the temporary copy.
```

[See full example on the playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/IEMwafEOZm)

Comment: Brilliant trick, thank you. Combined with `FieldByName`, this is quite powerful, albeit dirty.

Comment: what is meant by the "struct is addressable"?

Comment: @rakim: it means it you can take the address of it—e.g., it's a local variable or on the heap—rather than a temporary value such as the return value of a function.  You can read more here: https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/programming/GoAddressableValues

Comment: reflect.Value.UnsafeAddr of unaddressable value

Answer (score 25):

Based on [cpcallen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918797/2142441)'s work:

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

func GetUnexportedField(field reflect.Value) interface{} {
    return reflect.NewAt(field.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr())).Elem().Interface()
}

func SetUnexportedField(field reflect.Value, value interface{}) {
    reflect.NewAt(field.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr())).
        Elem().
        Set(reflect.ValueOf(value))
}
```

---

`reflect.NewAt` might be confusing to read at first. It returns a `reflect.Value` representing a pointer to a value of the specified `field.Type()`, using `unsafe.Pointer(field.UnsafeAddr())` as that pointer. In this context `reflect.NewAt` is different than `reflect.New`, which would return a pointer to a freshly initialized value.

**Example:**

```
type Foo struct {
    unexportedField string
}

GetUnexportedField(reflect.ValueOf(&Foo{}).Elem().FieldByName("unexportedField"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/IgjlQPYdKFR

Comment: That worked perfect for me. The code exaples are more structured, than in the [answer of cpcallen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918797/2894081) .

Comment: reflect.Value.UnsafeAddr of unaddressable value - seems like you need to check if field.CanAddr() before calling field.UnsafeAddr()

Answer (score 6):

[`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) can do it because it has access to unexported features of the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package, in this case namely for the `valueInterface()` function, which takes a `safe` argument, which denies access to unexported field values via the [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface) method if `safe=true`. `reflect.DeepEqual()` will (might) call that passing `safe=false`.

You can still do it, but you cannot use `Value.Interface()` for unexported fields. Instead you have to use type-specific methods, such as [`Value.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String) for `string`, [`Value.Float()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Float) for floats, [`Value.Int()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Int) for ints etc. These will return you a copy of the value (which is enough to inspect it), but will not allow you to modify the field's value (which might be "partly" possible if `Value.Interface()` would work and the field type would be a pointer type).

If a field happens to be an interface type, you may use [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) to get to the value contained / wrapped by the interface value.

To demonstrate:

```
type Foo struct {
    s string
    i int
    j interface{}
}

func main() {
    x := Foo{"hello", 2, 3.0}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)

    s := v.FieldByName("s")
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", s.String(), s.String())

    i := v.FieldByName("i")
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", i.Int(), i.Int())

    j := v.FieldByName("j").Elem()
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", j.Float(), j.Float())
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/u9fz2JeDyb)):

```
string hello
int64 2
float64 3
```

Comment: Ok but how can you know what the type is so that you can call the right method?

Comment: @UAvalos E.g. by calling [`Value.Type()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Type) (on the field's value).

Comment: wouldn't that result in a really painful switch block? ex: case Uint, case Uint8, Uint16, etc...

Comment: @UAvalos If you want to handle all types, unfortunately yes. If you just want to print its value, you may simply use `Value.String()` which does this inside it. Also note that `Value.Int()` for example handles all signed integer types (e.g. `int8`, `int16`, `int32`, `int64` and `int`) so these help you "ease" the pain.

Comment: Value.String() only returns the value if its a string. Otherwise it returns the string of the type of the value.

Comment: As @icza notes, the pain is not *too* painful. See https://play.golang.org/p/uB5KJYZzR5v for a sample that started with the [Laws of Reflection blog post](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection), to which I added some more accessors for private fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)

type Person1 struct {
    W3ID string
    Name string
}

type Address1 struct {
    city    string
    country string
}

type User1 struct {
    name      string
    age       int
    address   Address1
    manager   Person1
    developer Person1
    tech      Person1
}

func showDetails(load, email interface{}) {
    if reflect.ValueOf(load).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        typ := reflect.TypeOf(load)
        value := reflect.ValueOf(load)
        //#1 For struct, not addressable create a copy With Element.
        value2 := reflect.New(value.Type()).Elem() 
        //#2 Value2 is addressable and can be set
        value2.Set(value)     
        for i := 0; i < typ.NumField(); i++ {
            if value.Field(i).Kind() == reflect.Struct {
                rf := value2.Field(i)
                /* #nosec G103 */
                rf = reflect.NewAt(rf.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(rf.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
                irf := rf.Interface()
                typrf := reflect.TypeOf(irf)
                nameP := typrf.String()
                if strings.Contains(nameP, "Person") {
                    //fmt.Println(nameP, "FOUND !!!!!!! ")
                    for j := 0; j < typrf.NumField(); j++ {
                        re := rf.Field(j)
                        nameW := typrf.Field(j).Name
                        if strings.Contains(nameW, "W3ID") {
                            valueW := re.Interface()
                            fetchEmail := valueW.(string)
                            if fetchEmail == email {
                                fmt.Println(fetchEmail, " MATCH!!!!")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                showDetails(irf, email)
            } else {
                // fmt.Printf("%d.Type:%T || Value:%#v\n",
                //  (i + 1), value.Field(i), value.Field(i))
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    iD := "tsumi@in.org.com"

    load := User1{
        name: "John Doe",
        age:  34,
        address: Address1{
            city:    "New York",
            country: "USA",
        },
        manager: Person1{
            W3ID: "jBult@in.org.com",
            Name: "Bualt",
        },
        developer: Person1{
            W3ID: "tsumi@in.org.com",
            Name: "Sumi",
        },
        tech: Person1{
            W3ID: "lPaul@in.org.com",
            Name: "Paul",
        },
    }

    showDetails(load, iD)
}
```