# Calling an exported method on a unexported field

Tags: go, methods, reflection

I know, similar questions have been asked, but I found no answer for that case:

```
type ExportedStruct struct{ //comes from a dependency, so I can't change it
  unexportedResource ExportedType
}
```

I want to call an *exported* method `Close()` on `unexportedResource`.

What I did was:

```
rs := reflect.ValueOf(myExportedStructPtr).Elem() //myExportedStructPtr is a pointer to an ExportedStruct object
resourceField := rs.FieldByName("unexportedResource")
closeMethod := resourceField.MethodByName("Close")
closeMethod.Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf(context.Background())})
```

, which results in `reflect.flag.mustBeExported using value obtained using unexported field`.

This is quite annoying since I want to run more than one test which utilizes `ExportedStruct`, but I can't as long as the underlying resource is not used.

Since I can access private fields (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664837/access-unexported-fields-in-golang-reflect/43918797)) I have a bit hope that I'm allowed to access the public method of that field somehow, too. Maybe I'm just reflecting wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @icza's answer gives you reason why you should not do it, here is a way of how to do it using `reflect` and `unsafe`:

```
var t pkg.T
v := reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem()
f := v.FieldByName("t")
rf := reflect.NewAt(f.Type(), unsafe.Pointer(f.UnsafeAddr())).Elem()
rf.MethodByName("Print").Call(nil)
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/CmG9e4Bl9gg

Answer (score 5):

Unexported fields are for the declaring package only. Stop messing with them. They are not for you.

The linked answer can only access it by using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), which is not for everyday use. Package `unsafe` should come with a "not to touch" manual.

If you do need to access `unexportedResource`, make it exported. Either the field, or add a method to the type that calls `unexportedResource.Close()`. Or add a utility function to the package that does this (functions in the same package can access unexported fields and identifiers).

Comment: Thanks so far. `ExportedStruct` is comes from a dependency, so I have not access to that. I'll add to the question. Regarding "not for you". It's not something I enjoy doing, and reflection in general is something I'ld love to avoid. But some API aren't just as well designed as they should be, especially in (neverending) v0-iterations.

Comment: @NotX Using reflection is fine, using `unsafe` is what you should avoid. But what you want is not possible with reflection, only with (also) using `unsafe`.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that what you are trying to do is impossible through reflection.

Below is the implementation of reflect.Call:

```
func (v Value) Call(in []Value) []Value {
    v.mustBe(Func)
    v.mustBeExported()
    return v.call("Call", in)
}
```

As you can see there is an explicit check (i.e. `mustBeExported()`) if `Value` was obtained from an exported field or not.

Typically there is a reason why fields are not exported. If you want to manipulate that field you will have to use methods implemented by the `ExportedStruct` struct.

If you can modify the code where `ExportedStruct` is defined, you can easily implement a wrapper `Close` method on that. For example:

```
type ExportedStruct struct{
  unexportedResource ExportedType
}

func (e ExportedStruct) Close(){
  e.unexportedResource.Close()
}
```

Comment: You're right, `func (v Value) Call(in []Value) []Value` was exactly where I ended up in. I forgot to mention that I can't modify the place `ExportedStruct` came from. I've added that. Thanks!