# How can I clone a strings.Builder in Go?

Tags: go

The Go programming language's standard library exposes a struct called `strings.Builder` which allows for easy building of strings through repeated concatenation in an efficient way, similar to C# or Java's `StringBuilder`.

In Java I would use `StringBuilder`'s constructor to "clone" the object, like this:

```
StringBuilder newBuffer = new StringBuilder(oldBuffer.toString());
```

in Go, I can only see the following two-line way:

```
newBuffer := strings.Builder{}
newBuffer.WriteString(oldBuffer.String())
```

and no other `.Clone()` an initializer method (which I might have just not found yet).

Is there another way that would be more brief/concise than the one I have presented?

Comment: Sure. Add your own function with the **two lines** it takes to clone the string builder, then it will only take one line to clone for the caller.

Comment: The WriteString method can fail so it returns two values, a string and an error. I'm not sure how these are implemented in C# or Java but I'd imagine that if they could also fail some kind of exception handling would be required.

Comment: @Grizzle The WriteString method is declared to return an error so that StringBuilder satisfies the io.StringWriter interface, not because WriteString can fail.  No error checking is needed.

Comment: @Gavin of course, that would be the final option... I just wanted to check that there wasn't another more standard/idiomatic form that I was missing. I'm sorry for bothering you with my curiosity!

Comment: If you look through the source code of builder.go, you'll see a lot of the functions there are 3 lines long (the same length of the function to clone this string builder, when you count the `return ...`). Would you also argue for just writing those other sets of 2 lines everywhere they are used? (just some food for thought)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Going into unnecessary detail for curiosity's sake...**

After considering [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Builder), here are your main issues:

1. The only exported way to read data out of the Builder is the `Builder.String` method.
2. It is not safe to copy a `Builder` value once you have manipulated it.

Let's look at this version:

```golang
newBuffer := strings.Builder{}
newBuffer.WriteString(oldBuffer.String())
```

My first thought about why this isn't desirable is because the `Builder` internally uses a byte slice (mutable data type), and returns a string (immutable data type).  Even though a string's underlying representation is the same as a byte slice, due to this mutability rule it would require a copy to convert to string.  This means that by the time you write the string to the new buffer, you're already on your second copy when your task intuitively only requires a single copy.

Actually taking a look at the [source code](https://golang.org/src/strings/builder.go), however, we'll see that this assumption is wrong:

```golang
func (b *Builder) String() string {
    return *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(&b.buf))
}
```

Using the `unsafe` package, the `strings` package basically "hacks" the buffer (`[]byte`) directly into a `string`.  Again, these data types are the same on a memory level:  A pointer to the start of the string or slice, and a pointer offset describing how many bytes long the string or slice is.  These data types are just headers, so no copying of the buffer has occurred here.

This creates the uncomfortable situation where you have a string which is supposed to be immutable, but you still have a byte slice *somewhere* that could mutate those underlying bytes.  The package is called `unsafe` after all, and this is a good example of why that is.

Because the `strings.Builder` is purely a "builder", i.e. it can only create new parts of the string and never modify data that's already written, we still get the immutability of our string that the language "guarantees".  The only way we can break that rule is by gaining access to the internal `buf` of the `Builder`, but as that [field is un-exported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664837/how-to-access-unexported-struct-fields), you would again need to employ `unsafe` yourself to access it.

## Summary:

The straightforward method you came up with, while perhaps a line (*or two*) longer than one might hope for, it is the definitive and correct way to do it.  It's already as efficient as you're going to get, even if you bring out the more gritty features of Go like `unsafe` and `reflect`.

I hope that this has been informative.  Here are the only suggested changes to your code:

```golang
// clone the builder contents. this is fast.
newBuffer := strings.Builder{}
newBuffer.WriteString(oldBuffer.String())
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess that the underlying byte slice isn't really accessible outside the `strings.Builder{}`, so the unsafe invocation inside the `.String()` method is probably not a big deal. It's also good to know that it won't do two copies instead of one. Well wriiten, thanks again!