# How to access a unexported nested struct field from struct using reflect?

Tags: go, reflection

I am trying to access a nested struct (`time.Time`) within a struct using the `reflect` package. However, when trying to access it as an `interface`, I get the following error:

`reflect.Value.Interface: cannot return value obtained from unexported field or method`

How can I access this struct natively?

**Example:**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    t time.Time
}

func main() {
    foo := Foo{t: time.Now()}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(foo)
    f := v.FieldByName("t")

    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", f, f) // reflect.Value {13454110244426743808 1 0x5378e0}
    t := f.Interface().(time.Time)

    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", t, t)
}
```

**Go Playground:**
https://go.dev/play/p/O_jLStsd339

Comment: You can’t. Unexported means unaccessible.

Comment: @Volker No? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42664837/how-to-access-unexported-struct-fields/43918797#43918797

Comment: @tomwassing using unsafe almost everything is possible, but it can't be done with reflection alone. How does this question differ from the one you are citing?

Comment: @tomwassing. No. unsafe is _the_ way to that kind of problems nobody want's. Just switch to C if you think that's clever.

Comment: @DylanReimerink Thanks Dylan, I'm going to look into that!