# How to convert to typeof(field)?

Tags: go

Given something like this:

```
type Foo struct {
  x int
}

type FooFoo struct {
  foo *Foo
}

type Bar struct {
  x int
}
```

Where `Foo` is hidden (in my case due to vendoring), how can I create a FooFoo struct with a valid foo entry?

If `Foo` were available, I could do

```
foofoo := &FooFoo{ foo: &Foo{5} }
```

or even

```
foofoo := &FooFoo{ foo: (*Foo)&Bar{ 5 } }
```

But I can't find a way to do it without mentioning `Foo`.

I think I would need something like:

```
foofoo := &FooFoo{ foo: (*typeof(FooFoo.foo)) &Bar{ 5 } }
```

Comment: You won't be able to typecast Bar in this way. Maybe you could look into using interfaces of some sort?

Comment: Vendoring per se does _not_ "hide" types. Could you come up with a real example? Yours does not really show the actual problem.

Comment: An example of this issue is described [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12432): Essentially the type `T` from the a.go vendored in b is inaccessible outside of b.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set the private method from another library [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981651/in-go-is-there-any-way-to-access-private-fields-of-a-struct-from-another-packag). However,
the library should have an appropriate constructor. The library should have a method that looks like

```
func FooFooGenerator(appropriateInfo int) FooFoo {
 ... Library does the work 
}
```

Comment: The problem is not that it's a private field, it's that Foo is not available due to vendoring. If Foo was not vendored the problem would not exist. Unfortunately it does not have the constructor.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by vendored.

As far as I can tell you mean its a private variable (has a lower case letter in the struct)
If it is a private field in a library you didn't write there should be a method or you aren't using the library as intended (or it was written poorly)
If it is a library you wrote, make it public?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to export a "constructor" function for `FooFoo` and keep your `foo` unexported.

```
func NewFooFoo() *FooFoo {
    f := &foo{ /* initialize foo */ }
    return &FooFoo{foo:f}
}
```

Then clients of you package will have access to `NewFooFoo`, and `FooFoo`, but not `foo`.

And as for casting `Foo` to `Bar`, not sure why you would want that, but you can do it, if you are on **Go1.8+**, this way `(*Foo)(&Bar{ 5 })` [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/l696pw-Poh).