# How to skip a failed test

Tags: go, go-testing

In go, are you allowed skip a test that has already failed?

Context:

I have a [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) which I cannot currently determine the cause of. It causes some tests to sometimes fail.
By examining various logs I can identify the failure mode. I would like to do something like:

```
if t.Failed() {
    if strings.Contains(string(suite.Stdout), "connection reset by peer") {
        t.Skip("Skip Test failed ")
    }
}
```

The tests are valuable enough that I want to run them in CI despite the heisenbug so this is just a temporary workaround.

This doesn't work. Is there a way to retrospectively skip a test if it fails?

Comment: may be better to make to invest the time now and make your tests more granular - and thus be able to skip the problematic section (and any tests that are dependent on those).

Comment: No. Go‘s support for time travel is pretty bad.

Comment: You have total control over what's reported as a failure; if you don't want a test to be marked failed under some circumstances, then don't call `Error`/`Fail`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is **no**. You can skip a test or fail it but not both.

The designers of go consider trying to skip a test as trying to subvert the test framework
so you should not try to do this:

See for example https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16502

This is [documented](https://godoc.org/testing#B.SkipNow) but its easy to miss:

> If a test fails (see Error, Errorf, Fail) and is then skipped, it is still considered to have failed.

If you have a reliable way of detecting the heisenbug you should run it before making any test assertions. So rather than:

```
// execute
executeThingBeingTested()

// verify
assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)

// recover if needed
if t.Failed() {
    // detect heisenbug
    if strings.Contains(string(suite.Stdout), "connection reset by peer") {
        t.Skip("Skip Test failed ")
    }
}
```

You should instead structure your tests like:

```
// execute
executeThingBeingTested()

// skip if needed
if strings.Contains(string(suite.Stdout), "connection reset by peer") {
    t.Skip("Skip Test failed ")
}

// verify
assert.Equal(t, expected, actual)
```

This means that you cannot alternate between multiple execution and verification stages in a single test but its good practice to have only a single execution and verification stage in each test anyway. i.e. [four phase testing](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/test-driven-development/9781941222997/f_0026.xhtml)

Now if you *really* **really** want to do it you can go low-level. This is probably not a good idea but included for completeness. Peering down the rabbit hole may help show you don't want to go there. This takes in consideration [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981651/is-there-any-way-to-access-private-fields-of-a-struct-from-another-package) and how the `testing` package is [implemented](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?s=21002:21025#L595)

```
    t := suite.T()

    // low-level hackery - undo the failed state so we can skip a test
    pointerVal := reflect.ValueOf(t)
    val := reflect.Indirect(pointerVal)
    member := val.FieldByName("failed")
    ptrToFailedFlag := unsafe.Pointer(member.UnsafeAddr())
    realPtrToFailedFlag := (*bool)(ptrToFailedFlag)
    *realPtrToFailedFlag = false
```

If this level of hackery is not enough to convince you what a bad idea this is you might want to note the implementation of `fail()` at the time of writing:

```
        // Fail marks the function as having failed but continues execution.
   605  func (c *common) Fail() {
   606      if c.parent != nil {
   607          c.parent.Fail()
   608      }
   609      c.mu.Lock()
   610      defer c.mu.Unlock()
   611      // c.done needs to be locked to synchronize checks to c.done in parent tests.
   612      if c.done {
   613          panic("Fail in goroutine after " + c.name + " has completed")
   614      }
   615      c.failed = true
   616  }
```

You can see that as soon as Fail() is invoked any parent tests are also marked as having failed. So if you are using something like [testify/suite](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/suite) to organise tests into suites, to `unfail` a test you  would also have to `unfail` the parent test but *if and only if* no other tests in the suite have failed. So altering the testing() package to  allow skip to occur after fail interacts poorly with the idea of nested tests.